# Django Many to Many Query Set Filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm able to query my database below to get the result that I want but I don't want to have to iterate through all of the author objects, just the ones that have more than one post. There is a many-to-many relationship between Authors and Posts with the Many-To-ManyField on the Post. Does anyone know how to make this more efficient?

```
for author in Author.objects.all():
    if len(author.post_set.all()) > 0:
        print author
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
for author in Author.objects.filter(post__isnull=False):
    print author
```